# Why did Thomas throw his suitcase when Swan asked for it?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-romantic-englishwoman

In *The Romantic Englishwoman*, We can see here *Thomas* throws his suitcase when *Swan* asks for it.

[image]

Well, I thought, it contains some important documents or money like in most movies.
But *Elizabeth* checks the contents of the suitcase and it's all empty books & pencils etc.

[image]

My question is why did he throw them?